# How to use «entonces»

Tags: uso-de-palabras, adverbios

How and when do I use *entonces*? I know it means something like "and then" but how do I use it in context?

I don't understand how to use *entonces* in a sentence. I think I understand what it means, but in what context is it appropriate?

Comment: Same thing as English "then": it can express time (after that) or consequence (so).

Answer (score 7):

"Entonces" is used wherever you would use "then" in English.

Some examples

> - Cuando llegue la ayuda **entonces** podremos saber que pasó
>     When help arrives, **then** we can find out what's happened...
> - Escuchamos la conmoción, **entonces** paró.
>     We heard the commotion, **then** it stopped.
> - Si te gustan los duraznos **entonces** disfrutarás el postre
>     If you like peaches **then** you will enjoy the dessert

A different example could be expressions containing *entonces* that also translate as *then* like this one:
- **En aquel entonces** la vida era más simple.
- **Back then**, life was simpler.

Comment: Very helpful, although I've never heard the third example. I'll roll it around on my tongue and try to assimilate it in that context.  I assume I need the entire phrase: en aquel entonces for it to make sense as "back then."

Comment: *En aquel entonces* or *en ese entonces* = "back then".

Comment: Yes, You are both right. It is better to say "back then". Thanks @pablodf76. I corrected my answer

Answer (score 2):

I will add an example to the perfectly written answer by DGaleano.

In this case I think that **entonces** does not mean **then**:

> ¿Entonces, te parece bien?
>
> *So, do you think it is ok?*

Comment: If you need to expand another user's contribution, add a comment to their answer.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18624)

Comment: Ok, thanks for your advice

Comment: Thanks @Neo for the addition. It still stands that whenever you use "then" you can use "entonces" but it is also true that some other things like this use of "so" can be made into "entonces". **Then, do you think this is wrong?** 

Answer (score 0):

Entonces more accurately translates to "In that case". Google translate has it wrong y'all. There are other ways to say in that case in Spanish, I already know this. But that is exactly how entonces is used every single time.

Comment: I think that if you look in the dictionary https://dle.rae.es/entonces?m=form you will find that your answer is only half true.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/25859)